# How can I change the package name of Android app that has no build.gradle but still get upstream changes?

Tags: android, git

I would like to clone https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Contacts and make some changes. One of these changes would be to change the packagename, but there is no build.gradle with an applicationId that I can change. If I change the package= in the AndroidManifest.xml then I also need to change the folder structure. I am thinking this will make pulling in future upstream changes very difficult correct?

Is there a way to change the package name without changing the folder structure? Or is there a way to have git handle this change correctly?

Comment: Without gradle it is complex, error-prone and time-consuming. But you can create new project with required package-name and necessary configuration and then copy your existing code and resources into the new one. I think this can be the best procedure to do the needful.